# python write more then one line into csv

Tags: python

I am web scraping a site and have what i need in Python but when I write it to a cvs file I only get the first line.  Not exactly sure how to print multiple line.  the web scrape grabs 69 lines and I need all of them.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

```
g_data = soup.find_all("h4", {"class": "prod-title"})
p_data = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "amount"})


for g, p in zip(g_data, p_data):
    c = (g.text, p.text)
    print(g.text, p.text)

a.writerow(c)
b.close()
```

Comment: Can you fix your code indentaton? It doesn't look right at all.

Comment: Please check the indentation of your code - it's currently illegal, so that code won't even run. Most likely the line `a.writerow(c)` is not indented but should be.

Comment: Do you `close` the file inside the loop? **Upd:** `writerow` must be inside the loop, `close` outside.

Comment: You need to put `a.writerow(c)` inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`writerows`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) instead of `writerow`,

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    do_something()
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I forgot about the indentation, still getting used to Python.  So the following code works perfectly.  The writerows almost works but gives a comma after each character.  Thanks guys

```
for g, p in zip(g_data, p_data):
    c = (g.text, p.text)
    print(g.text, p.text)
    a.writerow(c)
```

Comment: The comma is the default delimiter. If you'd like to use `\t` as the delimiter, try this `writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')`